# Rational integer solutions of a linear Diophantine equation of cyclotomic integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry, computational-number-theory

I am working with lattices in $\mathbb{C}$, and I want to know whether a certain vector is an element of the lattice.

In particular, suppose my lattice vectors are $a$ and $b$ and I want to know whether $c$ (a Gaussian or Eisenstein integer) is in the lattice.  The problem reduces to existence of rational integer solutions to the linear diophantine equation $ax+by=c$.  Is there any known conditions to determine whether the Gaussian/Eisenstein integer solutions obtained (usual Bezout's) are rational integers?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are probably better off writing everything in terms of a basis over $\mathbb{Z}$, expressing the condition as a matrix equation and using the Smith normal form or another of the standard methods of dealing with integer matrices.

Comment: That is precisely what I am trying to avoid, going to the matrix setting.  I want to stay in the complex plane for some further generalizations.  Thanks anyway!